# How do I replace multiple elements?

Tags: c#, string, replace

For example,

```cs
    string myString1 = "abcdef";
    string myString2;
    myString2 = myString1.Replace("a", "abc").Replace("b", "bcd");
```

The output will be "abcdcbcdcdef".
I want my output to be "abcbcdcdef".
I know that you could do that with a StringBuilder, but is there
a shorter version?
I need to do this with a large number of characters (> 100).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The simplest approach is probably to loop over the characters of the string:

```cs
string myString1 = "abcdef";
StringBuilder result = new StringBuilder();
foreach (char c in myString1)
{
    if (c == 'a') // if the character is a, append abc
    {
        result.Append("abc");
    }
    else if (c == 'b') // if the character is b, append bcd
    {
        result.Append("bcd");
    }
    else // otherwise append the character verbatim
    {
        result.Append(c);
    }
}
string myString2 = result.ToString(); // produce a string from the StringBuilder
```

This produces "abcbcdcdef" as desired.

---

Another approach would be to use regular expressions with a custom evaluator:

```cs
string myString1 = "abcdef";
string myString2 = Regex.Replace(myString1, "[ab]", new MatchEvaluator(
    m => m.Value switch {
        "a" => "abc", 
        "b" => "bcd", 
        _ => m.Value 
    })
);
```

The regex `[ab]` will match the character `a` or the character `b` and pass this to the evaluator in `m.Value`. You could use ranges here (e.g. `[a-z]`), which would pass any character in the alphabet to the evaluator method. Since our "other" part of the switch statement just returns the original value, you can use ranges that are larger than you actually want to replace values for.

This also produces "abcbcdcdef".

Comment: How could you re-replace that? (abcbcdef -> abcdef)

Comment: I'd probably be tempted to modify the regex to `abc|bcd`, etc. and then switch the match around (e.g. `"abc" -> "a"`), though I suspect this approach _might_ have issues.

Answer (score 0):

If you have *large* number of characters, I suggest extracting data, let it be a dictionary
with `Key` being a character to find and `Value` string to put:

```
Dictionary subs = new Dictionary<chra, string> {
  {'a', "abc"},
  {'b', "bcd"},
  //TODO: add your rules here 
};
```

then you can easily query the string with a help of Linq:

```
using System.Linq;

...
string myString1 = "abcdef";

string myString2 = string.Concat(myString1
  .Select(c => subs.TryGetValue(c, out var s) ? s : c.ToString()));
```